# displaying dialog during module restore causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: no splash screen available

Tags: rcp, netbeans-platform

I have application built on top of Netbeans Platform and I need to do some checks during loading of one of the modules and display a dialog if some of the check fails to let the user to decide what should happen.

Insipired by this tutorial https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-login.html I created installer for the module and put the checks and dialog display to the installers method `restore()`.

```
public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

    @Override
    public void restored() {
        if (check()) {
            DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notify(myDialogDescriptor);
            //...
        }
    }
```

This works but causes the splash screen to be closed and later there occurs an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no splash screen available
at java.awt.SplashScreen.checkVisible(SplashScreen.java:197)
at java.awt.SplashScreen.update(SplashScreen.java:324)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash$SplashPainter.repaint(Splash.java:401)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash$SplashPainter$1.run(Splash.java:442)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What can I do to prevent this exception?

Comment: Did you try opening a JDialog instead of using DialogDisplayer. Maybe that causes the splash screen to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this exception in a simple standalone module. This seems to be a [known bug in NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=245165). A possible work around is to use WindowManager.invokeWhenUIReady() to delay display of the dialog until the main window opens like in this code example.

```
public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

@Override
public void restored() {
    WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NotifyDescriptor.Confirmation dd = new NotifyDescriptor.Confirmation("Do you want to proceed?");
            Object result = DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notify(dd);
            if (result == DialogDescriptor.OK_OPTION) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But this workaround may not be acceptable if your requirement is to display the dialog and take action before the main window opens and is displayed.